# Hierarchy viewer doesn't display items

Tags: android, hierarchyviewer

When i open hierarchy viewer perspective doesn't display items description. How to fix this?
[image]

Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Check that red message in the Console view to see if it gives you more clues. You might also need to restart your emulator and/or the **`adb`** daemon.

Comment: @CommonsWare [2014-04-21 16:48:09 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device

Comment: @CommonsWare I restart adb. And nothing happens.

Comment: You might need to restart your emulator.

Comment: @CommonsWare thats a real device.

Comment: @CommonsWare no result.

Comment: [How can I  Use Hierarchy Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055690/6521116)