# hierarchy viewer deprecation warning

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms, hierarchyviewer

I had used hierarchy viewer in the past for examining the app UI. On using the tool today I get this warning

```
vihaan@trojan:~/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/tools$ ./hierarchyviewer 
The standalone version of hieararchyviewer is deprecated.
Please use Android Device Monitor (tools/monitor) instead.
```

I have eclipse running and when I tried to use monitor , I encountered the "debugger can not attach to port" problem.

What is the proper way of using monitor from eclipse and does it provide same functionality as hierarchy viewer did ?

Comment: This may help [How can I  Use Hierarchy Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055690/6521116)