# Does Android Studio have a Hierarchy Viewer or Layout Inspector?

Tags: android, android-studio, hierarchyviewer, layout-inspector

I tried searching on here but couldn't find the answer.

I'm looking for a way to launch the [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) from within Android Studio, rather than having to launch it at the command-line. I've recently migrated to Android Studio from Eclipse, and this functionality was available under the DDMS set of tools in that IDE.

I've looked under the "Android" toolbar, and can see the screen-shot functionality there, but not the hierarchy viewer. I've also looked under **Tools > Android** in the menu system, and it's not there either.

Comment: [How can I  Use Hierarchy Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055690/6521116)

Comment: [From the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer): *Hierarchy Viewer is deprecated. If you're using Android Studio 3.1 or later, you should instead use Layout Inspector to inspect your app's view hierarchy at runtime. To profile the rendering speed of your app's layout, use [Window.OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener.html) as described in [this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html).*

Answer (score 86, accepted):

DDMS, Hierarchy Viewer, openGL Tracer etc all moved into Android Device Monitor.  To access:

1. In Android Studio:  "Tools" menu > Android > Android Device Monitor
2. In ADM: "Window" Menu > Perspective
3. Click on Hierarchy Viewer.

Comment: it make you lose adb connection in android studio, so there should be a better way to do this

Comment: I can't find it. There is no Window or perspective button inside the Android Monitor window. The top android studio window menu also doesn't have a perspective item.
All I see in Android Monitor are logcat, memory, CPU|GPU and network tabs.

Comment: @rockgecko, you should open 'Android Device Monitor' which is different than the 'Android Monitor' in Android Studio. Check again the step 1. in Alexander answer.

Comment: I can't find the hierarchy viewer neither in the sdk/tools directory nor in the Android Device Monitor after I upgrade my Android Studio to 2.3. Do you know how to solve it ？

Comment: Edited post to be slightly clearer. You have to click the "Window" menu along the top of Android Device Monitor.  From there click on the "Perspective" menu item.

Answer (score 34):

### Android Studio 4.0

There is a new live layout inspector. **View > Tool Windows > Layout Inspector**

Later versions of Android Studio 4.x also have it directly under **Tools > Layout Inspector**

For more information on its usage see [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/layout-inspector-1f8d446d048) or the [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector).

### Android Studio 3.2

The layout inspector is now found directly under tools. **Tools > Layout Inspector**

### Android Studio 3

The layout inspector can only be found under **Tools > Android > Layout Inspector**

### Android Studio 2.2

Instructions from [original link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html) on how to open the Layout Inspector:

> To open the Layout Inspector, first launch your app on a connected
> device or emulator. Then open the **Android Monitor** [image] window, select your
> device and app process, and then click **Layout Inspector** [image]. You can also
> open it by clicking **Tools** > **Android** > **Layout Inspector** in the menu
> bar.

Comment: Has this completely replaced the Hierarchy Viewer?

Comment: @MattPennington Once the layout inspector is complete that is the intention as mentioned in the linked article but I have not yet seen anything official announcing the hierarchy viewer as deprecated.

Comment: The main problem is that Layout Inspector doesn't have view profiling. And for me, it's the most important part of hierarchy Viewer. So, until it gets it, Hierarchy Viewer still useful.

Comment: I agree with @Gaket I'm using the layout profiler on AS 3.1 and I can't get a simple view of the layout depth for example.

Comment: @MattPennington They have stopped developing Hierarchy viewer anymore. Read in documentation.

Comment: @Gaket I agree.