# Android SDK hierarchyviewer command not found (Android Studio, Mac OS)

Tags: android

I try to launch hierarchy viewer from my `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools` directory, and it says

```
bash: hierarchyviewer: command not found.
```

Although I can see the `hierarchyviewer` tool is in the directory by typing `ls`.

If I type `which hierarchyviewer`, nothing happens. I tried other questions from StackOverflow and nothing worked. Any idea?

Comment: Refer to [Where is Hierarchy viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45052557/6521116)

Comment: [Does Android Studio have a Hierarchy Viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25390405/6521116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools` is not in your `PATH` variable. Then you'll have to start it via `./hierarchyviewer` from the `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools` directory (or via `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/hierarchyviewer` from anywhere).

Comment: Thanks! The command `./hierarchyviewer` launched it. I get a message: The standalone version of hieararchyviewer is deprecated.
Please use Android Device Monitor (tools/monitor) instead. Probably not going to be much use.

Comment: I couldn't find it in the latest build version. Android has deprecated it :(