# Android: Hierarchy Viewer doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-device-monitor

I am using Android Studio 2.3 on Mac Sierra and I could not find Hierarchy Viewer when I open Device Monitor. There is no viewer on the perspectives list. Does anybody know why is that?

Comment: @keyur9779 I did wrote that there is no hierarchy viewer there.

Comment: My bad, I got your Question in wrong way.

Sorry :)

Comment: Same here on MacOS Sierra. I looked up in the release notes: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html. But they don't tell anything about the Hierarchy Viewer. Maybe it is because we updated from 2.2. Could you try a new installation?

Comment: @unlimited101 no, I didn't do it and I am unable to do it now.

Comment: [Does Android Studio have a Hierarchy Viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25390405/6521116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't comment, no rep.

After updating to the latest build tools, hierarchy viewer and a bunch of other stuff was removed from the tools directory. I downloaded the tools separately from the Android Studio download page and it included the hierarchy viewer. Not sure what's going on, but it seems updating build tools in Android Studio removes the hierarchy viewer.

Edit: Hierarchy viewer is listed under the deprecated features from Build tools 25.3.0

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017

Comment: Hierarchy Viewer was a great tool, and a a lot of function of it is missing from Layout Inspector. It should not have been removed!

Answer (score 2):

According to google information(http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017)，hierarchy view is deprecated，and we should use Layout Inspector now
(http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-inspector)

Answer (score 1):

It's not gone, it's location has changed

`Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor > Window > Open perspective > Hierarchy View`

Comment: It's gone. RIP hierarchy view.

Answer (score -1):

The name has changed and the location also has changed,

> Tools > layout inspector