# Hierarchy view layout in android

Tags: android

I want to show hierarchy in a layout i am using [mindfusion code but its not free](http://www.mindfusion.eu/onlinehelp/droiddiagram/Android_Studio.htm) i want something like this

[image: this kind of structure]

Is there any .jar file tutorial site?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Does Android Studio have a Hierarchy Viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25390405/6521116)