# Hierarchy Viewer is gone

Tags: hierarchyviewer

It used to work well.But recently I upgraded my `Android Studio` to 2.3 and I find the hierarchy viewer disappears.I can't find it both in the `sdk/tools` directory and the Android Device Monitor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Android Studio have a Hierarchy Viewer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390405/does-android-studio-have-a-hierarchy-viewer)

Comment: I saw this and it doesn't work.I still can't find the hierarchy viewer.

Comment: [How can I  Use Hierarchy Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055690/6521116)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Latest build tools (25.3.0) removes hierarchy viewer.

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017

Comment: I found it in Tools -> Android -> Layout Inspector (in the main menus).

Comment: Hierarchy Viewer is not the Layout Inspector. Similar functionality, but different tools.

Comment: Any other alternative to measure the layout rendering performance?

Answer (score 4):

"The Layout Inspector available in Android Studio 2.2 is an early release. It's a work in progress that will supersede the Hierarchy Viewer tool once it is feature complete. For now, it provides a quick solution to inspect the view properties of your layout without leaving the IDE. " I find it in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-inspector.

According to it the Hierarchy Viewer is removed and we should use the layout inspector instead?

Comment: what's more, the Layout Inspector always gives me an error "Error obtaining view hierarchy: Unexpected error: empty view hierarchy"

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the Android Studio with path 
`Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor > Window > Open perspective > Hierarchy View`

You can refer this [**very detail post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055690/6521116) for more.