# Horizontal RecyclerView wrap_content doesn't work well on samsungs?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

TL;DR - I'm using an horizontal recycler view with wrap_content width on each cell, and it's working as expected on everything except samsung devices.

my list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scope_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_scope_state_normal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scope_text"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="2/2017"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

now, this is how it looks on a samsung s3 with this code:
[image: bad behaviour]

and this is how it looks if i change width of the relative layout in list_item.xml to 80dp:
[image: 80dp]

now, as you can see the texts have different width and with a fixed width i am missing letters in long words, wrap_content should set the width according to the text view width, but on samsungs this doesn't work, it just stretches the layout.. am I missing something?

Comment: Small not related comment. Why do you need relative layout? If you can just use textview

Comment: give that man a hug, I think this will fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the wrapping `RelativeLayout` as said by Eugen in the comment and use the recyclerview's internal system of [ItemDecorator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) instead for drawing the nice background instead.
this should fix your UI

also, you can dump the view hierarchy using the [Android Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390648/1056359) and see what the actual values are for the S3